# SQL multiple SUM and GROUP BY using different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure query which references an orders table and a product table. It lists the number of sales and total sales value of each product for a given month and year.

```
SELECT pCode, [Products].prodTitle
    , COUNT(*) AS Sales
    , SUM(amountBilled) AS SalesValue
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Content ON pCode = [Products].prodCode
WHERE DatePart(Month, orderDate) = '3'
AND DatePart(Year, orderDate) = '2024'
GROUP BY pCode, [Products].prodTitle
```

*In the actual query the month and year are parameters.*

I now want to add another column which gives the total number of sales for each product - that is, without WHERE condition selecting the month and year.

Can anyone please tell me a simple way to do this - ideally within the same query. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, syntax like `DatePart(Month, orderDate) = '3' AND DatePart(Year, orderDate) = '2024'` is *not* SARGable and not performant. Use date ranges.

Comment: Skip the WHERE, instead use case expressions to do _conditional aggregation_. (E.g. `SUM(case when DatePart(Month, orderDate) = '3' then amountBilled else 0 end)`.)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your query FROM clause includes tables ``Orders`` and ``Content``. Columns ``[Products].prodTitle`` and ``[Products].prodCode``  could not be bound.

Comment: To add to the "not sargable" discussion. Assuming the parameters are integer values named `@Year` and @Month, the **correct** way to write the `WHERE` clause looks like this: `WHERE  orderDate >= DateFromParts(@Year, @Month, 1) and oderDate < DATEADD(month, 1,   DateFromParts(@Year, @Month, 1))` This will run **MUCH** faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    pCode,
    [Products].prodTitle,
    COUNT(*) As Sales,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(Month, orderDate) = '3' AND DATEPART(Year, orderDate) = '2024' 
                THEN amountBilled 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) As SalesValue,
    SUM(amountBilled) AS AllSales
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Content
    ON pCode = [Products].prodCode
GROUP BY
    pCode,
    [Products].prodTitle;
```

Comment: Looks good but i think the COUNT(*) part needs to have the conditional logic applied to as well, or if he wants both

Answer (score 0):

This is small improvement of @tim-biegeleisen answer. I just advice to avoid from data manipulation in condition:

```
SELECT
    pCode,
    [Products].prodTitle,
    COUNT(*) As Sales,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN orderDate BETWEEN '2024-03-01' AND '2024-03-31' 
                THEN amountBilled 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ) As SalesValue,
    SUM(amountBilled) AS AllSales
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Content
    ON pCode = [Products].prodCode
GROUP BY
    pCode,
    [Products].prodTitle;
```

Comment: Sorry. Updated the credit :)

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
SELECT prodCode, prodTitle,yy,mm,Sales,SalesValue,totalSalesValue
from(
  SELECT p.prodCode, min(p.prodTitle) prodTitle
    ,DatePart(Year, orderDate)yy ,DatePart(Month, orderDate) mm
    ,COUNT(*) AS Sales
    ,SUM(amountBilled) AS SalesValue
    ,SUM(SUM(amountBilled))over(partition by p.prodCode) AS totalSalesValue
  FROM Products p
  left JOIN Orders o ON o.prodCode = p.prodCode
  GROUP BY p.prodCode,DatePart(Year, orderDate),DatePart(Month, orderDate)
)g
where mm = 3
   and yy = 2024
```